# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Iteration variable cannot be null

Tags: java, spring, iterator, iteration, thymeleaf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qDdT.png)> Been stuck on this for a few days.  I believe that the issue has to do

> with the class itself.  Or the relationship between the class in
>   question and the class its column is joined on.
>
> Here are my classes: 
>   **Mod**

```
package com.matt.Keyword.models;
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Mods")
    public class Mod {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;

        @NotNull
        private Integer role;

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, message = "An entry is required")
        private String entry;

        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private Integer userid;

        public Mod(Integer role, String entry) {
            this.role = role;
            this.entry = entry;
        }

        public Mod() {
        }

        public int getId() {

            return id;
        }

        public int getRole() {
            return role;
        }

        public void setRole(Integer role) {
            this.role = role;
        }

        public String getEntry() {
            return entry;
        }

        public void setEntry(String entry) {
            this.entry = entry;
        }

        public Integer getUserid() {
            return userid;
        }

        public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
            this.userid= userid;
        }

    }
```

**Account**

```
package com.matt.Keyword.models;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

    @Entity
    public class Account {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int id;

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 3, message = "Try again")
        private String name;

        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, message = "A password is required")
        private String password;

        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private Integer userid;

        public Account(String name, String password) {
            this.name = name;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Account() {
        }

        public int getId() {

            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {

            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {

            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getPassword() {

            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {

            this.password = password;
        }

        public Integer getUserid() {
            return userid;
        }

        public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
            this.userid = userid;
        }

    }
```

> Account and Mod classes are very similar and share a relationship with
>   the user_id column in the user class.

**User**

```
package com.matt.Keyword.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Size(min=3, message = "Try again")
    private String email;

    @Size(min=1, message = "A password is required")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private List<Account> accounts;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private List<Mod> mods;

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {}

    public int getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getEmail() {

        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {

        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {

        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {

        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }

    public void setAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }


    public List<Mod> getMods() {
        return mods;
    }

    public void setMods(List<Mod> mods) {
        this.mods = mods;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return email + " " + password;
    }
}
```

> The exception gets thrown when I load the index page from my mods
>   controller.  I am using thymeleaf to render views.  Here is my mods
>   controller.  The Mods database has objects saved to it and in this
>   controller during debugging the attribute being passed to the view
>   contains a populated list of Mod objects.
>    **ModController**

```
package com.matt.Keyword.controllers;


    import com.matt.Keyword.models.Mod;
    import com.matt.Keyword.models.User;
    import com.matt.Keyword.models.data.ModDao;
    import com.matt.Keyword.models.data.UserDao;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import javax.validation.Valid;

    //test commit note
    //second try
    //third try
    /**
     * Created by LaunchCode
     */
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("mod")

    public class ModController {

        @Autowired
        private UserDao userDao;

        @Autowired
        private ModDao modDao;

        @RequestMapping(value = "")
        public String index(Model model, HttpSession session) {

            if (session.getAttribute("currentUser") == null) {

                return "redirect:/keyword/login";
            }

            session.getAttribute("currentUser");
            model.addAttribute("title", "Mods");
            model.addAttribute("mods", modDao.findAll());
            return "mods/index";

        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String displayModForm(Model model, HttpSession session) {

            if (session.getAttribute("currentUser") == null) {
                return "redirect:/keyword/login";
            }

            model.addAttribute("title", "Add a new mod");
            model.addAttribute(new Mod());
            return "mods/add";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String processAddModForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid Mod newMod,
                                            Errors errors, Model model, HttpSession session) {

            if (errors.hasErrors()) {
                model.addAttribute("title", "List of Mods");
                return "mods/add";
            }
            User currentUser = (User) session.getAttribute("currentUser");

            session.getId();

            currentUser.setId(currentUser.getId());

            newMod.setUserid(currentUser.getId());

            modDao.save(newMod);

            return "redirect:";

        }

    }
```

> Here is the mod/index page using thymeleaf.

**mod/index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
    <head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>

    <body class="container">

    <h1 th:text="${title}">Default Title</h1>

    <p th:unless="${mods} and ${mods.size()}">No current mods</p>

    <nav th:replace="fragments :: navigation"></nav>

    <p th:text="${session.currentUser.email}"></p>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Entry</th>
        </tr>
            <div th:if="${mods} != null">
                <tr th:each="mod : ${mods}">
                    <div th:if="${mod.userid} == ${session.currentUser.id}">
                        <td th:text="${mod.role}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${mod.entry}"></td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </div>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

> The exception seems to be associated with the for th:each statement. 
>   Particularly with the "mod" iterator variable.
>   Here is the stack trace for the full error:
>   **Trace**

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/mods/index.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/mods/index.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardEachTagProcessor' (template: "mods/index" - line 21, col 17)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardEachTagProcessor' (template: "mods/index" - line 21, col 17)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Iteration variable cannot be null
    at org.thymeleaf.util.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:37)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Each.<init>(Each.java:49)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.EachUtils.composeEach(EachUtils.java:169)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.EachUtils.internalParseEach(EachUtils.java:94)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.EachUtils.parseEach(EachUtils.java:65)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardEachTagProcessor.doProcess(StandardEachTagProcessor.java:59)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    ... 67 more
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance for just taking a look if
you have the time.

[Debugger in mod controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcZNc.png)
[Here is  a to link to my repo if you want to download it and give it a run.](https://github.com/matsui23/Keyword)

[Hibernate exception in session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGo9W.png)

[Edit to mod/index controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qDdT.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue turned out to be quite a tricky one. The story of its resolution is as follows ...

Judging by the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Iteration variable cannot be null
```

there was an iteration in a thymeleaf template that had a `null` variable being iterated over. The only use of `th:each` I could find was:

```
<div th:if="${mods} != null">
    <tr th:each="mod : ${mods}">
         ...
    </tr>
</div>
```

So it seemed that `mods` was `null` and hence `th:each="mod : ${mods}"` is the where the issue lies.

However there was a check for this in place with `<div th:if="${mods} != null">`. Or was there? Would the following be more useful:

```
<div th:if="${mods != null}">
```

ie. moving the `}` so that the `null` check is within the expression.

That didn't help, so the result of `modDao.findAll()` was checked and there were two elements found. So it had to be something else.

Reviewing the [basics of iteration in Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration-basics) suggested that perhaps the collection being returned by `findAll()` was not one of supported types that `th:each` can iterate over.

So this collection was copied into an `Iterable` and given a different name and the problem was solved.

Interestingly, if the iteration variable was given the name `mod` the problem still occurred. Turns out `mod` is a keyword in Thymeleaf and is use for the modulo operation (`%`).

Ultimately, there were two issues with apparently correct code:

1. The DAO returned a collection but not one that could be iterated over by `th:each`; and
2. `mod` is a keyword in Thymeleaf and shouldn't be used as a variable name.

Comment: Hey Dave,  thanks for the suggestions I tried fixing the typo and it hasn't made a difference.  I ran the program in the debugger to check the value of findAll().  Adding a screen grab of the debugger above, its under the link "Debugger in mod controller"

Comment: @matsui23 OK, so there's two items in `mods`, so that's not the issue. Perhaps the line in error is `<div th:if="${mod.userid} == ${session.currentUser.id}">`. This should probably be `<div th:if="${mod.userid == session.currentUser.id}">`. If changing that doesn't work, can you check whether `session.currentUser` is not `null`.

Comment: I've just noticed further up the stacktrace it points to `template: "mods/index" - line 21, col 17`. Which bit of Thymeleaf does that point to?

Comment: In checking my session during debugging I found these exceptions.  Posted an image link above

Comment: Hmmm, what is the type of collection returned by `modDao.findAll()`? Perhaps it's not a type that Thymeleaf can iterate over. You could try taking the result of `findAll()` and putting it into a `List` and adding that to your model instead.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I am going to try that suggestion later today.

Comment: OK, let me know how you go. I'm keen to know what the issue is.

Comment: Morning Dave,  I got it to work attempting what you suggested above but I am still confused about why.  Later on when I can get my laptop on wifi I will link a photo of what I did.  Ultimately, I loaded the modDao.findAll() into an iterable<Mod> named testList.  Then passing testList into the model and that displayed the data properly in the template.  I made small syntax changes you recommended in thymeleaf as well but they worked both ways.  I attempted to name the new iterable under the "mods" naming I tried before and that gave me the original exception.  So I am curious as to why that is?

Comment: Thanks again for your help regardless, you helped me work through the issue.  I will post some images and update my original post so you can see the changes.  I would still like to understand why using the iterable instead of the list syntax, even with the same variable, would throw the same exception?  Could it be a reserved key of a sort in thymeleaf?

Comment: I added a pic in the original post that shows the iterable I used to contain the findAll() method return.  I also included a shot of my thymeleaf template.  Main difference I am seeing is that testList is an iterable and before mod was simply declared as a list.  One curious thing to note is if I change testList naming to "mod" still declared as an iterable and change the variable name in thymeleaf that wont work.

Comment: @matsui23 I've updated my answer based on your success and your comments. In brief, looks like there were two issues: the return type of `findAll()` is not iterable in Thymeleaf; and `mod` is a keyword.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Comment: the hint with the reserved "keyword" helped me in my case. my variable was named "eq", which is reserved for equality comparison in thymeleaf. the error message was misleading here. thank you for pushing me into the right direction. ;)

Comment: No worries. Funny how things can still help, even after a long time.